# Advantages of paid Java Application Servers?

Tags: java

What are the advantages of Weblogic or Websphere over Glassfish or JBoss, since they may reach costs of millions of dollars?

Edit: Is there additional functionality? The all are Java EE Full Certified.

**The question is about technology, not business or marketing. From the technological POV how are the servers different?**

Comment: -1 Would you care to back that question up with some numbers and specific use scenarios?  Your question sounds too close to [Q&A is hard](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @GlenH7: What possible scenario could you provide for using Notpad++ other than writing and reading text documents? The same here, the scenario here is Enterprise Java Applications. The sums don't really matter - some are free some are not. All of them are supposed to do the same thing. As for Q&A is hard, I'm not planing to buy anything; I'm not an architect (this would be a dumb question to be put by an architect). Also, as you can see, the question can be answered.

Comment: Millions of dollars?  You might have a bit yet before being _there_.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen That's what the Red Hat guys say: http://howtojboss.com/2012/03/26/head-to-head-jboss-v-ibm-tca/

Comment: @m3th0dman first of all this is JBoss trying to look better than IBM, second - I do not believe that the original poster is at a position where they can fully utilize 128 or 256 cores.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I am the original poster; the problem is not the money here but the technology. What's different in the technology since it costs (doesn't matter how much, but it costs)?

Comment: support, tooling, extra facilities - it is only in recent years that full, certified application servers have been available for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list (note that not all of the points may applay in every case):

- Better performance
- Better management/admin tools
- Better integration with various other products
- Better support - usually included in the license costs.
- Someone to blame when things go wrong

Note that you can get paid support for JBoss and Glassfish as well (in the latter case via a separate "Oracle GlassFish Server" edition).

Comment: I don't see any point applying to Websphere here, oh wait, maybe the last one !

Comment: @Jalayn: don't underestimate the value of a sales rep number management can call and scream at, even if there is no technical benefit at all.

Comment: Ha! You're right, I didn't think of it that way!

Answer (score 2):

All the complaint servers (whether paid or unpaid) will have all the features that are mandated by the Java EE standards. I guess however there are areas where the paid servers may excel. For example the facility to provide efficient clustering and monitoring (plus obviously the support) is something that paid servers usually boast. I guess Application server clustering is not that is something used by all applications and different paid servers may have better offering in terms of extra tools.

Answer (score 2):

The old adage "nobody ever got fired for buying IBM" applies here.

Also, the open source salesmen can't wine you, dine you and take you on paid vacations.

Answer (score -4):

There is certainly no technical benefit at all to Websphere or Weblogic. It's the perception that going with IBM or Oracle as your vendor is the safe choice.

Comment: Down vote by IBM or Oracle employee? Where's the comment?

Comment: Unsubstantiated assertion gets an unexplained downvote, seems natural. And that entitled reaction isn't going to help...

Comment: Check the rules of logic. You can't prove a negative. What are the technical benefits of Websphere/Weblogic over Glassfish/JBoss? Also check the dictionary - that isn't what "entitled" means.

Comment: You made that ridiculously broad statement, you back it up. If even the rules of logic said (which they actually don't, "you can't prove a negative" is total bullshit) that you can't, then why the hell did you make it? As for the dictionary: you feel entitled (look it up, also "entitlement bitch" for more details) to get a comment explaning any downvotes. Well, you aren't. The "IBM or Oracle employee" thing just makes you sound paranoid.

Comment: The onus is on the claimant to prove the positive. You can't, which is why you're just prattling on with more and more horseshit. When you downvote and don't comment, Stack Exchange displays a large message saying you should comment, so ACTUALLY it's site policy.

Comment: The horseshit is purely on your side. You made a claim, you prove it. Or at least give ANY information what that claim is based on. That you think you don't have to do that because it's a negative statement is idiotic beyond words. And here's one technical benefit: Weblogic allows you to replicate session state (for failovers) across subnets and even across clusters. Glassfish can only do that within a cluster that's on the same subnet. So there you go, ridiculously broad statement proven wrong.

Comment: As for "site policy" the message says "please consider adding a comment if you think the answer can be improved". So ACTUALLY you are not entitled to a comment.

Comment: The question itself states correctly that all are Java EE Full Certified. There is another answer that is essentially the same as mine: "The old adage "nobody ever got fired for buying IBM" applies here." Enterprise Java is largely a domain for large, established businesses. I said perception that IBM/Oracle are the safe choice. Large companies have long chains of command. Making a decision that can navigate through that chain and get approval isn't easy. Perception is essential. If you think a better answer is that Weblogic has unique features, why don't you give that as an answer?

Comment: I think a good answer to the question would be "Customers may want the larger Weblogic/Websphere suites which encompass much more than java app servers." When I answered I looked at the existing answers, particularly the one that cited "better performance" and "better mgmt/admin tools". These claims have been made over the years for Weblogic/Websphere and in fact Weblogic/Websphere have never been demonstrated to be more performant and their admin tools are horrible. That was the basis of my "no technical benefit at all" statement.